# How to store Joda Time (any) in Spring JPA with some SQL-compatible column type?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jodatime

I am learning how to access databases with Spring Boot JPA.

I wrote an application with some entity, containing [Instant](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html) field:

```
@Entity
@Table(
   name = "MEAL",
   uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"USER_ID", "TIMESTAMP_FIELD"}))
public class Meal {

   //private static DateTimeZone defaultTimeZone = DateTimeZone.UTC;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @ManyToOne//(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
   private User user;

   // @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) if non-Joda time
   //@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime") 
   @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP_FIELD")
   private Instant timestampField;
```

I was unable to compile / run with `@Temporal` or `@Type` annotations, so they are commented out.

Also, I was unable to run with the setting of `spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes` in `application.properties`

It was causing an error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.registerTypeOverride(Lorg/hibernate/usertype/UserType;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

So, this line is also commented out.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/pdk
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

# Jadira requirement
#spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
```

Unfortunately, at final state I got some serialized/binary data in field content

[image]

Is it possible to have some SQL-compatible column type here?

**UPDATE**

I found, that the following annotation was working fine:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInstantAsTimestamp")
```

But why setting in `application.properties` does not work?

Comment: What do you mean you were unable to compile/run with the Jadira type annotation? What kind of errors did you get? Which JPA provider are you using? BTW - the `PersistentDateTime` works for Joda `DateTime`, not `Instant`, which is the type of your field, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Are you using compatible Spring Boot and Hibernate versions? Seems like binary incompatibility of the libraries. Which versions are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon the very same issue, and it turned out that the version of Jadira usertype.core I was using (5.0.0.GA) was binary incompatible with Hibernate 4.x SPI.

Switching to 4.0.0.GA did the trick and registering Jadira's types using `jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true` started to work.